# Node.js 0.8.15 npm Error: Cannot find module 'proto-list'

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed the latest Node.js (0.8.15) on Ubuntu 11.10 x64 by compiling from sources.

```
 ./configure --dest-cpu=x64
 make
 sudo make install
```

All was OK and Node.js was working perfect but npm doesn't want to work properly. It give the following error for any npm commands

```
Error: Cannot find module 'proto-list'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmconf/node_modules/config-chain/index.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
```

By the way, I am updating my Node.js  periodically and my previous version was Node.js 0.8.12 where npm worked properly. 
Does anybody know how to resolve this situation? Or what I did wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you want to require a module which is not installed!??

try to

```
npm install proto-list
```

Comment: Thank you for advise, but, as I talked, npm generates error on any commands including install:(

Comment: Wow, I have found the solution.

curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh > npm_install.sh
sudo ./npm_install.sh

after that npm is working properly