# npm update check failed

Tags: node.js, npm

Last night I tried to update my node and npm, it seemed to have been successful, however ever since then I have been getting this same error any time I try and run any npm command.

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing npm, but cannot get past this error message below.

Node version: v8.3.0

Error message I am getting:

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                      npm update check failed                      │
│                Try running with sudo or get access                │
│               to the local update config store via                │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /Users/veritystothard/.config │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
module.js:491
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'proto-list'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:489:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:517:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/config-chain/index.js:1:79)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
```

I'm not sure what other details to include here, if anyone has had this issue before I'd appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js 0.8.15 npm Error: Cannot find module 'proto-list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584852/node-js-0-8-15-npm-error-cannot-find-module-proto-list)

Comment: npm install (command work for me)

Answer (score 55):

Following is the answer from [github](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17946)

> Fix for windows, I got this message :
>
> npm update check failed Try running with sudo or get access to the
> local update config store via sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER)
> C:\Users.config
>
> so I went on to C:\Users.config and deleted the
> "configstore" folder. once I done this, next time a ran npm start, the
> folder was re-generated, and error stopped

Fix for OSX:

After two hours of try-and-fail I managed to solve the issue as follows:

1. go to folder /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
2. right-click on the folder node_modules > go to Get Info
3. update the permissions > add yourself and administrator account and set "read and write" for both
4. run in the terminal "npm install packageName"
5. if you still get the error, go to the same folder /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ and within the folder node_modules, update in the same way the permissions for the new package folder
6. try to run again in the terminal "npm install packageName"

That worked for me! Hope it could help somebody.

Comment: This worked for me. Already had full rights, but now the error has gone away.

Comment: For me the `configstore` folder was inside `C:\Users\<username>\.config`

Comment: This works in Linux as well. `rm -rf .config/configstore`

Comment: I was having issues with this today and it's not prompting the update anymore. Great solution!

Comment: @tiomno In fact for me running the recommended command in the error message also worked: `sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) ~/.config`

Comment: may be worth to try this before to see where configstore is, and the command to chown it: `find . -name "configstore" -type d 2>/dev/null | xargs -r -n1 echo sudo chown -R $(id -u $USER):$(id -g $USER)"`

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue on AWS server, i used this command to update the config permissions and the npm command worked smooth.

> sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER)  ~/.config

Answer (score 16):

If your are on macOS, you must update the config file. You just have to enter this command in your terminal:

```
sudo npm i -g npm
```

Comment: Excellent ... This comment works fine for me. But where I get this config file.

Answer (score 5):

I have similar error after node updating so i just delete directory **.config** and this help.

Comment: where i have this .config file ??

Comment: `C:\Users\User_Name\.config`

Comment: @SivaGanesh it's not a file, its a folder

Comment: Deleting your full `.config` folder is a bad idea, specially on linux. If you want to go the delete route, then only remove the `.config/configstore` folder.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Issue and how to fix it]

Run below command from a command prompt

Step 1 : (If possible open cmd as administrator)
 - npm install -g npm-check-updates

Step 2 : 
 - Open new command prompt and Create a new project

Answer (score 3):

I got a Windows 10 environment:

For me, first I did make sure all node.exe instances killed:

```
taskkill /t /f /im node.exe
```

Then I've updated npm to the latest version using [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates)

Finally, I deleted `.config` folder from user home `C:\Users\<USERNAME>`

That's solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to chown your entire `.config` directory (which contains configuration files from other programs), try:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) "/home/skaestle/.config/configstore/"
```

Comment: This worked for me! Very useful if you don't want to delete the .config dir (which you probably dont want it to happen)

Answer (score 2):

Try running the command prompt  `Run as administrator` mode, if that not solved your issue delete the `.config` folder under `c:\user\<name of the user>\` and then try running the command prompt `Run as administrator` mode.

Comment: Restarting prompt as administrator worked for me after deleting .config !

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error (npm update check failed) on a Centos 7 but not when installing node, just when loggin into the server and it was because there was no more space left. Deleted some files, updated the system and everything worked fine again.

Just in case somebody else comes to the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have a fixed that worked for me on OSX Catalina:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log
-------------------------------------
> node server.js

€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”
â”‚             npm update check failed              â”‚
â”‚       Try running with sudo or get access        â”‚
â”‚       to the local update config store via       â”‚
â”‚ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /tmp/.config â”‚
â””â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”
```

I ran the following code in the terminal and as suggested here: `sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /tmp/.config` & redeployed to my instance which still showed a degraded state.

I did this several times and this did not result in success.

Since I had a duplicate instance that was in the ready, so I didn't think it was a permissions problem on my local machine.

The following fix worked for me (please note that my code is deployed to ebs through  AWS CodePipeline":

> 1. Delete `package-lock.json` from your express/node project.
> 2. Run `npm i`
> 3. `git add && git commit -m "your commit msg" && git push`

In your aws console, go to **code pipeline** and verify your code deployed successfully.

Navigate to **Elastic Beanstalk**. If your code pushed successfully, you should see your instance updating.

After this the state of your EBS environment should be in the ready state.

Hope this helps someone out.

Comment: Awesome! I have had this error show up for various reasons. One time a file had been renamed locally and in the code, but not in git. This time i just couldn't figure out why. Deleting package-lock.json, commiting and then redeploying worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

I'm a windows user. I solved mine by going to the `/Users/<username>` right clicking the `.config` folder then in properties un-ticked the read only and apply

Answer (score 1):

worked for me after running below command

```
nvm use --delete-prefix version
```

Answer (score 1):

**Running the cmd with admin rights once was enough for me.**
Just did `npm version`.

After that it worked again also without admin rights.
I did not delete anything.

```
{
  npm: '6.13.6',
  node: '12.14.1',
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the user does not have sudo rights in a unix environment, remember the user name you want to issue the command with (-> USER). Then use

> su

Enter your root password. Then

> chown -R USER:USER .config

Other .config folders that were created using root are also changed. In my case changing `~/.config/nvw`s owner did the job (`chown -R THE USER YOU USE NPM WITH:THE USER YOU USE NPM WITH .config/nvm`)

Answer (score 0):

This issues come due to TWO reasons

1. You have no permission to read-write
2. Due to window settings folder is secured.

case 1st- just enable the read-write permission
case 2nd- if u have permission for read-write and still you facing the same issues, it means you system securities reject the request to write the file, because the file location is given in C drive

**solution** - JUST disable the firewall / Ransomware protection in windows 10. try again you will get the success.

Answer (score -1):

run script to check for update

```
sudo npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

and later update using `sudo npm`