# I get a warning that npm update check failed

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Following is the error message I get after installing npm packages

npm update check failed

Try running with sudo or get access
to the local update config store via

sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /home/ubuntu/.config

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm update check failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650300/npm-update-check-failed)

Comment: what's the question? npm tells you very clearly and explicitly what to do and what directory you need access to?

Answer (score 1):

Answer from [GitHub](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17946):

> Fix for windows, I got this message :
>
> npm update check failed Try running with sudo or get access to the
>   local update config store via sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER)
>   C:\Users.config
>
> so I went on to C:\Users.config and deleted the "configstore" folder.
>   once I done this, next time a ran npm start, the folder was
>   re-generated, and error stopped

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47861024/6279370)

If you are on a Mac, this might help

```
sudo npm i -g npm
```