# NPM can't be install on laravel project

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, npm-install, failed-installation

I've been working on my laravel 5.8 project.I'm using visual studio code. as I tried to run the command:
npm install on my visual code terminal. it said that my npm can't be update.
here's the screenshot for the issue[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoHJF.jpg)

Comment: Did the packages not install? That message only indicates that npm could not check whether there's updates available to npm itself

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm update check failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650300/npm-update-check-failed)

Comment: you can directly check the error message from the img that I posted along with the question