# npm start not working in react giving error npm update check failed

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am using react and when i use npm start to open a window to check my react app it gives the error:

> ```
>                     npm update check failed                   │
> │             Try running with sudo or get access             │
> │            to the local update config store via             │
> │ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) C:\Users\nikhil\.config │
> ```

I am not getting what is the problem please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm update check failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650300/npm-update-check-failed)

Comment: There is already an issue raised for the same in github : [npm update check failed](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17946)

Answer (score 0):

#### Aside from the quality of the question:

`Try running with sudo or get access` means that your current user has no access to that directory, where the `node_modules` are in. Use `sudo`, change the permission of the directory with `chmod -R 644`, `chmod -R 755` or switch to a user who has access to the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out works fine for me :

```
sudo rm -rf node_modules/
sudo yarn install 
sudo npm start
```