# Create react app is not working unable to process after it create package. Json

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, mern

While creating react app it only creating package. Json  after that nothing happening I update my npm and create-react-app also but still it not creating some one help me

Comment: You’ll need to have Node >= 8.10 and npm >= 5.6 on your machine check this one out and have a name in lower case

Comment: My npm version is 6.7.0 and node version 11.13.0

Comment: can u add the error or any message it's showing in the terminal along with command you're using

Comment: I am using create-react-app my-project

Comment: npm / npx ???? everything seems fine share your warning message in terminal

Comment: I am using create-react-app my-project. Next creating a nee React app In c:\Users\Username\Desktop\my-project and two Installing packages. This might take couple of minutes, Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template... Then I waited for more than 6 hours it is not proceeding after this commands

Comment: Same with npx create-react-app my-project

Comment: npx create-react-app my-project  this command should work delete the existing folder and try once

Comment: Tried same thing bro

Comment: try upgrading node to 13.1.0 unable to lock the issue since no error mentioned

Comment: Upgrade today I got npm update failed

Comment: npm update check failed                      │
│                Try running with sudo or get access                │
│               to the local update config store via                │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /Users/veritystothard/.config

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650300/npm-update-check-failed

Answer (score 0):

First check your node and npm version with node --version and npm --version commands respectively. If node >= 8.10 and npm >= 5.2 then try running npm install before running create-react-app.